# Convert regex to string in webdriver selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

**My HTML code:**

```
<select id="selectrepo" class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1 select ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched" ng-required="true" ng-model="locFrmdata" ng-disabled="!locPathdet" name="select" required="required">

<option id="dfltval" selected="selected" value="">Kiezen</option>

<option id="locDet+'0'" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="\keur\BVGO" ng-repeat="locationDet in childRepos track by $index">\keur\BVGO</option>
</select>
```

**This is the WebDriver code I'm writing:**

```
String repos =  new String("\keur\BVGO");
Select repo = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("selectrepo")));
repo.selectByVisibleText(repos);
```

and also

```
repo.selectByValue("\keur\BVGO");
repo.selectByVisibleText("\keur\BVGO");
```

How do I find this element?

Comment: what is issue??

Comment: im unable to select the option

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is about software engineering and is also abandoned by one-time user

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to escape special symbols?

```
repo.selectByVisibleText("\\keur\\BVGO");
```

Comment: repo.selectByVisibleText("\\\keur\\\BVGO"); .. I tried this but not working ..

Comment: repo.selectByVisibleText("\\\keur\\\BVGO"); .. Show error message like " Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ ) "

Comment: sorry, I meant two slashes. did yo try two slashes ?

Comment: yes, i have tried with two slashes also !! .. But didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the next xpath:

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='selectrepo']/option[text()='\\keur\\BVGO']")).click();`

Comment: Showing the same error message like " Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\ ) "

Comment: try again, I have updated with extra slashes. I have deployed html you provided on IIS and tested wit Java and Python API and it works for me:

Comment: I have tested these lines and they select proper value every time: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='selectrepo']/option[text()='\\keur\\BVGO']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='selectrepo']/option[text()='Kiezen']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='selectrepo']/option[text()='\\keur\\BVGO']")).click();

Comment: Sai, did you try code above ?

Answer (score 0):

**Why do you not use following:**

```
repo.selectByVisibleText('\keur\BVGO');
```

OR

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='selectrepo']/option[text()='\keur\BVGO']")).click();
```

Only single quotes disables interpolation.

Comment: Both this are not working .. giving the same error invalid special characters

Answer (score 0):

The below code works for me:

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("selectrepo")));
dropdown.selectByValue("\\keur\\BVGO");
```

You can also use `selectByIndex` for selecting the value;

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("selectrepo")));
dropdown.selectByIndex(1);
```